# SharePoint Architecture - WFE in DMZ / Search Server in internal network

Tags: search, architecture

Can I have this configuration?

**Corporate Network**

Query Server/Index Server service running on the repository server ( I will install web server component on this machine also)

**DMZ(Perimeter Network)**

Only Web Front end but no Query service

If I can have that configuration, will the extranet user be able to search for data, as he is hitting the Web front end which is in DMZ, but not the Query server which is in Corporate Network?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this but you will have to ensure the web front end can communicate to the query server, content db's and other services as required through the firewall.

A guide to the ports required for this kind of communication can be found [on this link](http://www.intheknow.it/mossports.ashx)

Basically you will need to open ports for SMB 
and SQL, there may be others but you will be able to figure out from the diagram in the link.

Comment: Link is dead. It truly is.

Answer (score 0):

You also need to ensure that the connection between your DMZ and your local LAN can handle the amount of datat that is copied to the web frontend(s).